# Tire pressure with load and heat

Tags: tires, dodge, pressure, ram

Running a ram 2500 pulling 10,000lbs 5th wheeler...truck door sticker and tire call for 80psi... when pulling the trailer in the summer the heat of the road increases the psi to 90 is that safe or should I reduce the psi 5lbs or so..any thoughts?????

Answer (score 13):

**As long as you are running Light Truck (LT) tires, you should be just fine.** Manufacturers take into account the tire pressure is going to go up due to heat buildup. This is why you check tire pressures when they are cold so you don't get a false reading on them. If you lower the pressures to 80psi when hot, you'd actually be causing your tires to overheat due to excess rolling resistance, which will deteriorate them faster and could possibly cause a blowout. Follow what your door sticker states and you'll be golden.

Comment: Indeed. If I were forced to mis-inflate my tires, I'd prefer to make the mistake of overinflating them rather than underinflating -- fewer things to go catastrophically/permanently wrong, at least in the short term.

Comment: I would think it's a question of degree. 5 psi are probably fine, 20 psi are probably not.

Comment: @xyious - Tires can handle far in excess of what you should run them at ... when a service center mounts the tires, they severely over-pressurize them (in comparison to the maximum pressure) to seat the beads. If you've ever watched them do it, it's when the loud "pop" happens. This is far greater than even the 20psi you mention ... mind you, they only put the pressure in to seat the beads, not much more, but that's still a lot more than 20psi. (Light truck tires will take more than passenger tires to accomplish this ...)